# Issue with stripping a variable?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell why the "C" is getting striped from the project name in the below code?I have the output and expected output"

INPUT:-

```
Total: %d 2
TRAINBUILD:       macOSfuture
PROJECT:          projectDrivercompNIC
TAG:              projectDrivercompNIC-1401
SHA:              5f6cc81d
    <change://problem/4046817> title1
    <change://problem/4135645> title2
Total: %d 12
```

OUTPUT:

```
 projectDrivercompNI
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
projectDrivercompNIC
```

CODE:-

```
import sys,re
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:  
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

project = ""
radar_count = ""
new_project = ""
for line in lines:
    #print "line:" + line
    if re.match(r'PROJECT:\s*.*', line):
        project = line.strip(r'^PROJECT:\s*')
        project = project.strip()
        #print project
        #print "project:" + project
    if re.match(r'Total: %d\s(\d+)',line):
        radar_count = line.strip('Total: %d')
        radar_count = radar_count.strip()
        #print radar_count
        if  radar_count !='0'  and radar_count != "" and project != new_project :
            new_project = project
            print new_project
```

Comment: strip doesn't remove a substring, it removes *any characters from the ends that are in the string you pass to it*. It also looks like you assume that it understands regex, it doesn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - how do I fix this?

Comment: Try `re.sub`, maybe? There's a lot of approaches